# Rails 3.x uploading a file via rest-client with S3 :: No such file or dir error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, rest-client

I have a an image file stored on S3.  I want to upload that file as form data to a remote site.

Controller line:

```
response = RestClient.post("#{BASE_URL}/processImage?language=#{LANGUAGE}&exportFormat=txt", :upload => { :file => File.new(asset.avatar.url) })
```

The asset.avatar.url is a paperclip stored file sitting on S3.  It's there.  It's publicly accessible.

But I keep getting Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory) with the url...that works!

I'm probably missing something simple here.  Anyone have any ideas?

** EDIT: SOLVED **

I used open-uri, then just used open().  It still downloads to the server, but at least it works.  And visually it looks simpler.  =)

Here's the fix:

```
require 'open-uri'
response = RestClient.post("#{BASE_URL}/processImage?language=#{LANGUAGE}&exportFormat=txt", :upload => { :file => open(asset.avatar.url) })
```

Open-uri is part of ruby, so you don't need to install a gem (ie: rest-client)  Just require it in your code.

I thought I'd need a .read in there somewhere, but it *seems* to work fine without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the file/contents before posting it with RestClient. File.new takes a filepath as argument, not an url.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I was hoping for a Rails automagical solution. =P

Comment: Found a solution (open-uri), that doesn't require a download to the server.  See my edit.

Comment: Open-uri is a nice wrapper for net/http that download you content when you call open(url). So content will still be downloaded to server before sending it with RestClient.

By the way, I think you need to call "read" to actually read the contents from the created StringIO-instance.

Comment: Well, this has definitely been an educational couple of days. You're absolutely right.  Goes to show that 1) I need to stop speed reading docs when looking for answers, and 2) I should trust people with 1500+ points...  =)